# how do i unhide spaces between words in a hangman game?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am making a hangman game, but there's something i can't figure out.

I am able to hide the letters using

```
guessed = "_"*len(guess)
```

but it also hides the spaces. for example if my word is 'the avengers' it will hide 12 characters instead of 11. how do unhide/leave the spaces alone? this is what i have so far:

```
def getHiddenWord():
    guess = getRandomWord().lower()
    guessed = "_"*len(guess)
    if "_" in guessed is " ":
        print(guessed.replace("_", " "))
    else:
        print("The Word is:", guessed)
    return guessed
```

Comment: `guessed = "_"*len(guess)` just makes a string of as many underscores as there are characters in `guess`. You've lost all information about where spaces are. You're better off simply replacing things that _aren't_ spaces in `guess` with _.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: One simple way is to loop through guess and change everything that isn't a space to a _.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.sub`

```
guessed = re.sub(r'\S', '_', guess)
```

`\S` would match any non-space character. So the above `re.sub` function would replace any non-space character from the input string with `_`.

*Example:*

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'the avengers'
>>> re.sub(r'\S', '_', s)
'___ ________'
>>>
```

or

```
>>> ''.join(['_' if not i.isspace() else i for i in s])
'___ ________'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that:

```
def getHiddenWord(guess):
    guessed = ''
    for c in guess.lower():
        if c != ' ':
            guessed += '_'
        else:
            guessed += ' '
    return guessed
```

The problem with your approach is that you use this:

```
guessed = "_"*len(guess)
```

It takes the whole length of the string and the empty space is also counted. If for some reason you need to exclude empty space in the count of len you need to use this:

```
guessed = "_" * (len(guess) - guess.count(' '))
```

But in your case you most likely don't need it.

Also note that the function `getHiddenWord(guess)` does not change your original word but creates a new one and returns it.